# How do I make a bat file that creates a dir and moves folders on an unknown computer?

Tags: batch-file

I'm hoping someone can give me the code or good example of how to create a bat file that does this - when a user drags my folder onto their computer and runs the bat in it, a directory should be created on that users computer in C:\DontKnowUsersComputerName\My documents\Visual Studio 2012\ and all the files should be moved into that folder. I obviously won't know the path of where the user puts it on their machine, but I want the bat file to figure out the location, and move those files to C:\DontKnowUsersComputerName\My documents\Visual Studio 2012\

Comment: Is there an environment variable that contains the computer name that you can use? On my box I have a %COMPUTERNAME% variable, but I am not 100% sure it is present on all systems.

Comment: @Laf:  The name he needs is associated with the logged in user, not the computer.

Comment: @Clifford Then _DontKnowUsersComputerName_ was kinda misleading :P

Comment: @Laf:  Yes I agree. It was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
if NOT EXIST "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\" mkdir "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Documents\Visual Stydio 2012\"
mkdir "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\newfolder
```

The user folder and drive are maintained in environment variables,

Comment: Thanks Clifford. That worked on my machine and will probably work for others too.

Comment: I am not sure weather HOMEPATH etc. are defined for all Versions of Windows; I checked it on Windows 7, and I figure if you are using VS2012, it might be reasonable to expect at least Win7.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: noticed you want these inside 'my documents' and possibly want the directory created.

inside batch file(cd to %USERPROFILE% works from anywhere):

```
cd %USERPROFILE%
md "My DocumentsB/Visual Studio 2012B"
cd "My DocumentsB/Visual Studio 2012B"
ECHO Test text >filename.txt
pause
```

If the directory already exists (as mine did), the make directory command just doesn't make a new one.

reference: http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified." Please test your answers before posting them. :-)

Comment: @Ken White On what OS? It works fine on Win7

Comment: I tested on Win7. It doesn't work for four reasons: 1) There's no `Visual Studio 2012` in `%USERPROFILE%` (it's in the `My Documents` subfolder), 2) there are spaces in `Visual Studio 2012`, so the entire thing (including `%USERPROFILE%`) needs to be in quotes, 3) I don't have a `Visual Studio 2012` folder on this machine, and 4) the user may not be running the batch file from the `C:` drive, so you need to account for that as well. (One or two of those you addressed in your edit after my original comment was made.)

Comment: How quickly I forgot that the batch file closing doesn't mean it was successful.  I'll go ahead and edit my answer with a test text file created in the final destination folder, which I'm 99% sure won't exist on any machine.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. (I didn't downvote, BTW; just suggesting some fixes before someone does.)

Comment: USERPROFILE on its own does not point to the user's "Documents" folder, but environment variables is the solution.  Enter the set command to get a list of all environment variables.

Comment: @Clifford I know, it doesn't need to.  The majority of my intent was an easy way to get to the current user's directory (%USERPROFILE% is also an environment variable for Microsoft systems - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Beyond getting there, I did the further md & cd commands which could be easily customized to any folder under the user's directory.

Comment: @panhandel:  It does *need to* in the sense that that is where the original question stated the folder must be. Your *intent* should be to answer the question accurately. `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` points to a user's "home" folder which need not be in the user's profile directory (it can be moved).

Comment: @Clifford Fair enough on the documents folder being movable, but I don't see that %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% points to any different location than %USERPROFILE%.  Both must be followed with either "\Documents\" per your example, or "/My Documents/" in mine.